# yarn on wsl ubuntu 18.0 vscode not using lock file

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, yarnpkg, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Hi Trying to run a yarn install on project on WSL Ubuntu 18.04 using vscode.  But yarn seems to not be using the yarn lockfile and I get errors about the wrong node engine when running yarn install....
cd-ing to the project directory and running sudo yarn install

```
yarn install v1.22.10
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error juice@7.0.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=10.0.0". Got "8.10.0"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

it looks like its just using yarn from the usr install and not the local project directory what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you have multiple versions of yarn, use the full path to the yarn version you want to use.

Comment: No i only have one version of yarn installed globally.

Comment: Looks like this post did the trick: